# onfocus not work for button

Tags: android

```
final View b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.find);
b.setOnFocusChangeListener(new  View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(hasFocus==true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(user_interface.this, "onfocus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //  b.setBackgroundColor(R.color.gray);

            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(user_interface.this, "lossfocus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked it. It works. Note that on Emulator the onFocus happens when you go to the button via scrolling the up/down arrow.

I have the following code:

```
btnSign.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                //Toast line...
            }
        }

    });
```

For button why have u used :

final View ??? May be thats the problem..

use Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.find);

Comment: He used final because otherwise he would have got a compilation error, because of the usage inside an anonymous class.

Comment: thanx , yes this work  with up/down key why it not work with mouse

Comment: on focus for the phone means exactly that the focus(cursor) is on the field. The mouse cursor is not detected in onFocus. In fact the mouse cursor cannot be detected at all.

Comment: i use this method but not work for me i want to visible progressbar on click and invisible this button not work kindly guide me about this even toast not show on click on mobile phone, here is my code

Comment: login.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            login.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            if (!hasFocus){
                login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loginBinding.userNameEt.setClickable(false);
                Toast.makeText(this, "not focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loginBinding.userPasswordEt.setClickable(false);
            }else
                Toast.makeText(this, "focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  });