# how to define focused button in my class?

Tags: android, button, focus

I have a button and I want when the button is focused (not pressed) some functionalities applied . (the button size get smaller and...)
but first I should define focused button to my java code like this:

```
 if (myButton.isFocused()) {
        //function here...
    }
```

but the function doesn't work! is this method right that is applied to my button(.isFocused())?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchView.isFocused always returns false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082745/searchview-isfocused-always-returns-false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onfocus not work for button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429218/onfocus-not-work-for-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a FocusChangeListener and listen for changes.

```
myButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // the button size get smaller and...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: not worked for me... I add this method to onCreate() but nothing happened

Comment: Add to XML properties of the button.
    
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

or in the code

    myButton.setFocusable(true);

And try again,